# Missing operand after 'Operator Name' operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dataview

I am filtering my gridview using dataview. I am passing the filter command to dataview as mentioned below;

```
string strFilter= " 0=0 ";

if (Session["SampleSession"] != null)
        {
            strFilter= strFilter+ " and Emp Name = '" + Session["SampleSession"].ToString() + "' ";
        }
dv.RowFilter = strFilter;  // Throws an error here!
```

It throws an error of Missing operand after 'Operator Name' operator in above line.

i believe there is small error which i am unable to catch.

Comment: What is `strFilter`'s value when it hits that line?

Comment: what is 0=0 in `string strFilter= " 0=0 ";` ?

Comment: @Maysam The "0=0" would be a placeholder so that you can easily append "and EmpName = 'Foo'" and still have a valid filter expression.

Comment: @Xor My guess right now (until you can give me the value of `strFilter`) is that your "SampleSession" variable has a single-quote character in it which is breaking the expression. Sort of a poor-man's SQL injection vulnerability. Could you possibly be passing an employee name like "Bob O'Hara"?

Comment: 0=0 and EmpName = 'Car Air Systems' is the value of strFilter when hits the error prone line

Comment: @Xor ok, that sounds fine. There's definitely a field called "EmpName" in your DataTable?

Comment: Yes there is a field name EmpName in my datatable. I checked that twice when assigning to dataset

Comment: What is the ***exact*** value of `strFilter` when this errors?

Comment: Is the code snippet you've provided the actual code? Your column name doesn't have a space in it, by any chance? eg [Emp Name] or [Employee Name]?

Comment: Yes.. the column name has the space in it. I got the actual cause of the error coming. How can that be avoided. Space is need in column name

Comment: That's the problem then. Wrap you column name in square brackets like I did above. No wonder we couldn't give you an answer!

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I've edited your question to properly reflect the error, and added an answer.

Comment: thats fine.. would be useful in future to others

Comment: @Xor by not responding to the repeated requests for the *actual* value of `strFilter`, you wasted a number of people's time trying to answer a question that ***did not contain the problem***. Just a recommendation for the future: post code that *actually causes the problem*; since you (by definition) don't understand the issue, it is all too easy to accidentally remove the actual cause when posting a question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is that "Emp Name" (the column name) contains a space and needs to be wrapped in square brackets in the filter expression:

```
strFilter= strFilter+ " and [Emp Name] = '" + Session["SampleSession"].ToString() + "' ";
```

Comment: Square brackets also solve problem with strange name like 10_vces in my situation.